# Can someone explain to me how to walk through this code?

Tags: c, string-concatenation, c-strings, strlen, pointer-arithmetic

I want to understand what this code is supposed to do, 'cause Code::Blocks doesn't show me enough to understand on my own.
The code in C language is down bellow:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct S {
   char *S;
};

int main(void) { 
    struct S *S = (struct S *) malloc(sizeof(struct S));
    S -> S = "123\0""45678";
    printf("%d", strlen(S -> S + 5) + S -> S[3]); 
    free(S);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your code? How did you wrote it, if you don't understand?
Edit: I'm sry, I overlook a "the" and read "... to understand my code ..."

Comment: @theSealion — I don’t see a claim that it is their own code.

Comment: This code is intentionally obfuscated. I suggest you to start with codes which do not try to confuse you but to make it *easy* to the reader to understand what they do.

Comment: It is not my code, I just want to understand it, that's all. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that you should not use spaces around the dot `.` or arrow `->` operators; they bind very tightly and spaces are inappropriate and an indication of a neophyte at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the code is invalid. In this call

```
printf("%d", strlen(S -> S + 5) + S -> S[3]);
```

there must be used the conversion specifier `%zu` instead of %d because the expression `strlen(S -> S + 5) + S -> S[3]` has the type size_t due to the usual arithmetic conversions.

During the preprocessing phase these two strings

```
"123\0""45678"
```

are concatenated in one string like

```
"123\00045678"
```

where \000 is one character in the octal notation.

So this expression

```
strlen(S -> S + 5)
```

yields the length of the substring `"5678"` that is 4.

This sub-expression

```
S -> S[3]
```

yields the character `'\000'`.

So `4 + 0` gives `4` that is outputted.

Comment: Please explain me in detail 2 things : the preprocessing phase where those 2 strings are concatenated into one(wich line of code shows it), and that strlen(S -> S + 5), how did it managed to  show only the last 4 digits. Thank you.

Comment: @painkiller In this expression S->S + 5 there is used the pointer arithmetic. So this expression points to the 6th character of the array. It is equivalent to &S->S[5] About the preprocessing phase what is unclear? The compiler concatenates two string with each other..

Comment: Ok, so the S->S+5, wich again is &S-S[5], wich is the index 5, but keeping in mind that this is an array, starting from index 0, it is the 6th element. I understand that know. And for the preprocessing phase, what you mean is that the compiler doesn't accept the "123\0""45678" variant, because there are 2 strings, instead of one? so it glues them together into one big string ? without any suplimentary code lines that force him to do that explicitly?(like strcat function does)? Thank you for your answers!

Comment: @painkiller The compiler accepts this record but joins  them together as one string.

Comment: And does it without any further explicit code to do so ? just as part of the compiler internal processing ?

Comment: @painkiller I already said that it is the preprocessing phase of the compilation. What is unclear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200179/discussion-between-painkiller-and-vlad-from-moscow).